# Getting nil values in Swift when i create new Instance to the class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I am getting problem in swift with the creating new instance to the class. I am setting a dictionary to HttpVo class  in the httpUtils but unable to get that dictionay in other place by creating new instance to the same class.

Thanks

[This is my demo project you can download source code here](https://www.facebook.com/download/1460766810889139/HttpHelper.zip)

Comment: Instead of having a zip file, paste your code here, it's much easier to help you.

Comment: Please add the relevant code inline in the question, and remove the download link to the zip file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `callApiWithData` return a object as `HttpResponseVO`.

You created a new instance in `ViewController.swift`, but you didn't set anything.

Try it.

```
self.httpVO = self.httpHelper.callApiWithData(dictParams, url: BASE_URL, httpType: httpType)
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be nice if you could add some explanation on why this is a valid solution.

Comment: Thanks !!.. Reming Hsu

Comment: This is right answer. Working fine for me. Here i am returning httpVo object in utility class but i am not returning object in ViewController. I Got the solution.. Thanks all